# Config XML TO XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

We have multiple configurations in our application and I'm trying to make a UI so the user has one stop shop to configure all the xml values. But instead of manually creating the UI screens, is there a way to generate the UI screens based of the xml key/value pairs? Just text boxes are fine.

Comment: I would bet XSLT could handle it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Textbox>..
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

(Have not tested the above code).  You could read in the values from XML and bind to ItemsSource.

Comment: So parse the xml file and every time I get a key/value I bind to the itemcontrol?